# A river runs through it. Do you copy?

Tags: riddle, haiku

> Earth girls are easy
>   Lets dance upside down, freak out!
>   We are family

What am I talking about?

---

<sub>Spoiler for second stanza</sub>

> Risque baseline hint
>  Good times, chic cosmic thing!
>  You might get lucky

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The river seems to be

> Nile

Explanation:

> **Nile Rodgers** is all over this puzzle

Earth girls are easy

> **Nile Rodgers** did the soundtrack for "Earth girls are easy"
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Girls_Are_Easy

Lets dance upside down, freak out!

> **Nile Rodgers** produced David Bowie's "Let's Dance"
>  **Nile Rodgers** produced Diana Ross's "Upside Down"
>  **Nile Rodgers** was a member of Chic with "Le Freak"
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Dance_(David_Bowie_album)
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upside_Down
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Freak

We are family

> **Nile Rodgers** composed "We Are Family"
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Are_Family_%28song%29

Risque baseline hint

> "Risqué" was the third studio of Chic
>  Chic was famous for funky bass lines
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risqu%C3%A9_%28album%29

Good times, chic cosmic thing!

> "Good times" was composed by Bernard Edwards and **Nile Rodgers**
>  **Nile Rodgers** produced "Cosmic Thing" for "The B-52's"
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Times_%28Chic_song%29
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Thing

You might get lucky

> **Nile Rodgers** wrote "Get Lucky" for Daft Punk and Pharrell Williams
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Lucky_%28Daft_Punk_song%29

Comment: oh! consider: part of your answer might be a response to the title